# Matrix to String output

Tags: java, string, matrix

I'm currently trying to figure out how to redifine my toString method so that it will display the matrix. Here's the code..

```
    import java.util.Random;


public class TextLab09st
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("TextLab09\n\n");
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(3,4,1234);
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix(3,4,1234);
        Matrix m3 = new Matrix(3,4,4321);
        System.out.println("Matrix m1\n");
        System.out.println(m1+"\n\n");
        System.out.println("Matrix m2\n");
        System.out.println(m2+"\n\n");
        System.out.println("Matrix m3\n");
        System.out.println(m3+"\n\n");
        if (m1.equals(m2))
            System.out.println("m1 is equal to m2\n");
        else
            System.out.println("m1 is not equal to m2\n");
        if (m1.equals(m3))
            System.out.println("m1 is equal to m3\n");
        else
            System.out.println("m1 is not equal to m3\n");
    }
}


class Matrix
{
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private int mat[][];

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols, int seed)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        mat = new int[rows][cols];
        Random rnd = new Random(seed);
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r ++)
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            {
                int randomInt = rnd.nextInt(90) + 10;
                mat[r][c] = randomInt;
            }
    }
    public String toString()
    {

        return ("[" + mat + "]");
    }
    public boolean equals(Matrix that)
     {
         return this.rows == (that.rows)&&this.cols == that.cols;
     }


}
```

I know how to display it and how to redifine the equals method, I feel like it's just late and I'm missing something silly. Sorry for any inconvience!

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to specify that it had to be shown as a 2 dimensional row x column display.

EDIT2: Now I'm having trouble redefining the equals method, as it is required for my assignment. I rewrote it to this:

```
public boolean equals(Matrix that)
      {
         return this.mat == that.mat;
      }
```

and it still outputs:

```
m1 is not equal to m2
m1 is not equal to m3
```

Is there any easy way to fix this?

Comment: what your current output and what you desire ?

Comment: my current output is simply the memory address of the matrix. I need it to be displayed 2 dimensionally (Row x Column)

Comment: for the equals, you should check if the rows and cols countr is the same and then you can check if the elems of the arrays are the same. you can use the double for loop like in the to string method to access each element and look if they are the same

Comment: Sorry, I'm very tired and I've been attempting to do what you said and I can't seem to check if the elements in the array are the same. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to make a nested loop for each cell in your matrix.

```
public String toString()
{

    String str = "";

    for (int i = 0 ; i<this.rows ; i ++ ){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < this.cols ; j++){
            str += mat[i][j]+"\t";
        }
        str += "\n";
    }
    return str;
}
```

As for the "equal" method, I'm not quite sure what is the criteria.
Does your application consider two matrixes to be equal if they both have the same number of rows and cols?

P.S.

Overriding the equal method is a very good practice, but it is a better practice to override the "hashCode" method as well.
Might not be relevant to your app, but it is important.

Hope that would help :)

Comment: Another thing i forgot to mention is that it is part of the assignment to rewrite the equal method. And yes it does check to see if both matrixes have a similar number of rows and columns. I realize now that this is irrelevant to what I'm trying to accomplish by rewriting this method.

Comment: Now I am having trouble writing the code for rewriting the equals method as well, as I can't seem to figure out how I would write it using something other than the rows and cols variables. Any hints or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Indeed, keeping the nuber of rows and cols as class members is redandent. instread you can add 2 methods to retrieve the number of cols and the number of rows and to use them in the equals method, here's how:

    public int numOfRows(){
     return this.mat.length;
    }
    public int numOfCols(){
     if(this.numOfRows() > 0)
      return this.mat[0].length;
     else
      return 0;
    }
    public boolean equals(Matrix that)
     {

     return this.numOfRows() == (that.numOfRows())&&this.numOfCols() == that.numOfCols();
     }

Answer (score 1):

Use [Arrays.deepToString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29):

```
public String toString()
{
    return Arrays.deepToString(mat);
}
```